# Stop Calling Div Function on click of anchor tag inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div onclick="fnOne()">
  <a href="#" data-target="#div2">text</a>
</div>
```

Now On Click of anchor tag fnOne() is also calling. #div2 data-target also working. Now how to prevent calling fnOne() on click of anchor tag and show only div2.

Comment: You need to stop the propagation of the event

Comment: I'm not sure that people will find this clear enough; could you provide some more code, or use something like jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
<div class="click">
  <a href="#" data-target="#div2">text</a>
</div>

$('.click').on('click',function(e){
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
/*call your function*/
});
```